# Max value of list isnt working?

Tags: python, list, csv

Why is python doing this? I am trying to get the max value of csv column? I used a custom function and also the built in one both return the same wrong resoult? What am i doing wrong?
[image: img1]

Comment: You're comparing strings: `max(zip(*data)[0], key=int)`

Comment: You're comparing strings, not numbers. `"70"` is greater than `"110"`.

Comment: In the future, please copy and paste text into questions rather than providing screen shots. They're not usefully indexed by search engines, can't be copied into the readers' own python interpreters, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do the comparisons as `int` not `str`. The following will give you what you want:

```
print max(zip(map(int, data)))[0]
```

#### Even better

As @Aशwini चhaudhary suggested,

`print max(zip(*data)[0], key=int)`

Comment: There's no need to create a new list.

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary, Yes I saw your comment. May I include that in my answer (unless you plan on doing it yourself, then i'll delete my answer) (PS: This is not for rep, I have already capped, I just want good answers to be available to the OP). Thank you

Comment: Yes, you can include that in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing strings not numbers. So the highest string is the one with the largest number representation of the characters, in your case '7'. The outcome is totally correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [3]: l=["22","33","25","13","44"]

In [4]: print max([int(x) for x in l])
44
```